# MSB3073 command exited with 1

Tags: msbuild, assembly-signing, strong-named-key, sn.exe

while signing for dll files command executed successfully but for .exe files i got error "Command exited with 1" .

exec Command="SN-R demo.dll ..\key.snk" 
 exec Command="SN-R demo.exe ..\key.snk"

Please help me how to solve this

Comment: More information would be helpful to users trying to diagnose the problem. Have you put in any research effort to see what might be causing this?

Comment: Above problem solved by installing Microsoft SDK 8.0

Comment: Go ahead and provide that as an answer; it might help future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I had installed Microsoft SDK 7.0

After uninstalling SDK 7.0 I have installed SDK 8.0 then problem solved